# Attaching bathroom door threshold

Tags: bathroom, doors, threshold

I just moved into an apartment where the bathroom was recently renovated. However, the threshold was quite loose. When I inspected it, it appeared that that threshold had just never been attached and pulled loose without any resistance at all. The threshold is some hard, composite material. It is between the tile floor of the bathroom and the wood floor of the hall. I'm not sure how to attach the threshold to the ground underneath it. Any advice? [image: The threshold]

[image: Underneath the threshold]

Answer (score 3):

I normally set a threshold of that sort in a bed of thinset mortar, taping off the edge of the wood.

You could also use construction adhesive.

If a **rental** apartment, contact the landlord and advise that the tile people seem to have not finished the job properly, rather than fixing it yourself. If it's a place you own, do what you will.

Comment: Thanks very much. That’s really helpful. Is there any brand of adhesive that you recommend?

Comment: They vary in availability around the world, and even within the same country. Aside from not particularly wanting "shill" for any particular brand, I might like a brand you can't even find. I honestly prefer to use thinset, but I can see the appeal of construction adhesive if this is the only thing you'll be doing. A major-brand polyurethane adhesive is my "generic" suggestion. Select one that claims water resistance for this application, as well.

Comment: Do you mean a flexible caulk-like polyurethanne adhesive or a liquid polyurethane adhesive like "gorilla glue premium"

Comment: Polyurethane **construction adhesive** which is "caulk like" in application but not very flexible when cured - not "glue" (i.e. for Gorilla, "heavy duty construction adhesive" not the liquid gorilla glue.) Solid gap fill is an important function in this application (thus my preference for using thinset mortar.)